# configure ec2 to run a script to download files from a sftp site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I want to configure `EC2 instance`, such that i can run script ( may be on a schedule) to download files from a sftp site. Doing some research , i found code samples ( see below), which connects to the server. I'm not sure if the following code will work for sftp (ssh ftp), do i need to configure ssh? how can i run this code in `EC2 instance`?
can i upload it to s3 and point it from ec2 to run this on `some schedule`?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
export PASSWORD="*******"
expect -c 'spawn sftp uname@ftpsite.com; 
expect "*Password: ";
send "$env(PASSWORD)\r";
expect "sftp>";
send "get some_file.txt \r";
```

Comment: You can setup cron task on the instance to run on schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this code in following ways

1. `connect your ec2 through ssh.`

- first allow inbound ssh traffic to your instance using security
  groups on port 22
- second find out the public IP of your instance

**NOTE:-** make sure you have created and downloaded a .pem file while launching your instance.

- then use this command to ssh into your instance `ssh ec2-user@your-public-ip -i /path/to/.pem/file`.
- once you are logged in to your ec2 instance you can run those
  commands.

NOTE:- this is one way to connect to your ec2 instance, you can also connect to ec2 via aws console, using browser connect if you dont want to type all that ssh command.(just a sleek process) but even if you choose this way to connect to your ec2, still you will need to configure your security group to allow ssh traffic.

2. `Now what if you want to schedule this?`

In Linux, we use `cron` daemon to schedule commands.

*The crontab is a list of commands that you want to run on a regular schedule, and also the name of the command used to manage that list. Crontab stands for “cron table, ” because it uses the job scheduler cron to execute tasks*

```
crontab -e //to make entries in cron
crontab -l //to list cron jobs
```

Crontab Format

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD
```

*Time intervals are denoted by numbers and operators filled in place of each asterisk in a Cron job’s crontab line. From left to right, the asterisks represent:*

- Minutes specified as a number from 0 to 59.
- Hours specified as numbers from 0 to 23.
- Days of the month, specified as numbers from 1 to 31.
- Months specified as numbers from 1 to 12.
- Days of the week, specified as numbers from 0 to 7, with Sunday
  represented as either/both 0 and 7.

Enter this in the editor (example)

```
30 08 10 06 * /home/ramesh/full-backup.sh
```

*This will execute the Full backup shell script (full-backup) on 10th June 08:30 AM.*

see this for examples and allowed values [cron examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: Could you please add one or two sentences for cron or how to run it on schedule?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra - thanks, so to put this in cron. I would ssh into my ec2 instance , then execute some commands to create/edit cron right? for that , doesn't this script needs to saved somewhere

Comment: it should be saved on your system. so that system knows where to find this script.

Comment: Updated my answer for better explanation, if it solves your problem, do accept it as solution to your question so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra - will do. I'm still not clear on script upload part though. You mentioned , it should saved on your system, i'm not sure how this all will work

Comment: if its ec2 instance based on linux ami, when you ssh, just use any editor like nano or vim.cd to desired directory for cd ~,then vim script.sh,then type in your script, save it for vim its `:wq!`and for nano `ctrl-x`, this way it can be saved to your ec2 instance.